# Polymorphism, Casting to Object, and Type Erasure

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, type-erasure

This is / are my very first question/s on Stackoverflow and I hope you might help me out with an understanding problem that I am having right now.

Let's say I am doing this:

```java
Object o = null;
String s = "Test";
System.out.println(o instanceof String); //This returns false
o = s;
System.out.println(o instanceof String); //This returns true
```

So far so good, but now when I do:

```java
System.out.println( ((Object) o) instance of String) //Still prints true
```

So why does this statement print true even though inside the print I cast o back to an Object class? Even

```java
System.out.println(((Object)o).getClass())
```

prints that o is of class String. Why so?

This leads to my second question which has to do with Generics and Type erasure.
I looked at a code sample like this:

```java
private static <T> T cast(Object i){
    return (T) i;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Object o = null;
    try{
        o = main.<Double> cast("Test");
    }catch(ClassCastException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not cast properly");
    }

    System.out.println(o == null); //Prints false
    System.out.println(o instanceof String); //Prints true
    System.out.println(o instanceof Double); //Prints false
}
```

From my understanding of type erasure all generics T will be replaced with Object during runtime. When running the cast function what should happen is actually
something along the lines of `return (Object) i;`. 
As my first question above, why does `System.out.println(o instanceof String);` print true? Shouldn't o be of type Object?

Looking forward to your answers, thank you :)!

Comment: Assax91, please retitle this question and create a second question for your second question.  Questions are separated out in order to help make the most useful archive possible for future coders.

Comment: At least the appropriate tags are all there...do you think it is enough?

Comment: @Choirbean I think the question is fine. The issues are all related.

Comment: I was aiming for having the first question as an intro into the second one since they are basically pretty much the same question I believe. It was meant to be a bigger question seperated into two parts. 
So what would the way to go be? Split it or keep it?

Comment: I think I've been outvoted here.  I would make two questions and link the second one to the first, but I don't mind being wrong.  I'm often wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why does this statement print true even though inside the print I cast o back to an Object class?

You're just casting the reference to `Object`. The actual object is still that of `String` type. And `instanceof` check is against the actual instance, not reference type.

> prints that o is of class String. Why so?

`getClass()` methods return the `Class` instance of runtime object type.

> why does System.out.println(o instanceof String); print true?

As you notice, you're passing a `String` type as argument to your `cast()` method. So, even though the reference type is `Object`, again the actual object is of type `String`. Nothing special is going on here due to generics. The reasoning is same, and the result is also the same.

Comment: (1) First of thank you for your very quick response. However there is still something confusing me. Since o is basically a pointer to something in my memory and I am casting the reference, am I not acting upon the thing stored at o directly? Isn't it like functions act directly on objects since objects are passed by reference in Java (in contrast to primitives)?
(2)
I was expecting to get back an Object from the cast function, not a String because I am explicitly returning Object, but I think that is me getting the basics wrong. I should hit the books again I guess!

Comment: @Assax91 Everything is passed by value in Java. There is no such thing as pointer. What you've got is reference to an object. Casting it to a separate reference will result in a new reference type, that too pointing to the same object. So, the underlying object is not changing.

Comment: Oh damnit, after reading your answer again I think I got it now! Instanceof checks the class of the object at given reference and not type of the reference itself. So even though I cast o to Object, what's at that adress is still a String. Thank you!

Edit: Got ninja'd by you